# Is there a database of endgame positions with known perfect play?

Tags: endgame, database

Perfect play as in, it leads to checkmate in the least moves possible. Not just forced mates.

Comment: Look up tablebases.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is call Lomonosov table : [link](http://tb7.chessok.com)

It is all the positions with 7 or less pieces and the whole answer is known.